# How do you I reshape data from wide to long? Currently, I am getting an error

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I am working with Demographic and Health Survey (DHS) data. I want to reshape the data from wide to long. Below my steps with codes and error message, so you can get familiarize.

1. `HNIR62FL_data_1 <- read_sav("~/DHS/HNIR62SV/HNIR62FL_data_1.SAV")`
2. `obsHNIR62FL_data_1 <- subset(HNIR62FL_data_1, !is.na(V021) & !is.na(V022) & !is.na(D005))`
3. `myvars <- c("CASEID", "V013", "V021", "V022", "V025", "V106", "V137", "V190", "V714", "D005", "D104", "D106", "D107", "D108","v1014", "v1016", "v1023", "v1038", "v1039", "v1045", "v1113", "V701", "v1007_1", "v1007_2", "v1007_3", "v1007_4", "v1008_1", "v1008_2", "v1008_3", "v1008_4", "v1009_1", "v1009_2", "v1009_3", "v1009_4", "v1010_1", "v1010_2", "v1010_3", "v1010_4", "v1020_1", "v1020_2", "v1020_3", "v1020_4", "v1071_1", "v1071_2", "v1071_3", "v1071_4", "v1088_1", "v1088_2", "v1088_3", "v1088_4", "v1096_1", "v1096_2", "v1096_3", "v1096_4", "v1104_1", "v1104_2", "v1104_3", "v1104_4", "v1111_1", "v1111_2", "v1111_3", "v1111_4", "v1112_1", "v1112_2", "v1112_3", "v1112_4")`
4. `newobsHNIR62FL_data_1 <- obsHNIR62FL_data_1[myvars]`
5. `newobsHNIR62FL_1_long <- reshape(newobsHNIR62FL_data_1, varying = c("v1007_1", "v1007_2", "V1007_3", "v1007_4", "v1008_1", "v1008_2", "v1008_3", "v1008_4", "v1009_1", "v1009_2", "v1009_3", "v1009_4", "v1010_1", "v1010_2", "v1010_3", "v1010_4", "v1020_1", "v1020_2", "v1020_3", "v1020_4", "v1071_1", "v1071_2", "v1071_3", "v1071_4", "v1088_1", "v1088_2", "v1088_3", "v1088_4", "v1096_1", "v1096_2", "v1096_3", "v1096_4", "v1104_1", "v1104_2", "v1104_3", "v1104_4", "v1112_1", "v1112_2", "v1112_3", "v1112_4"), direction = "long", idvar = "CASEID", sep = "_")`

Error message:

1. Error in `reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying`  :

   ```
   'varying' arguments must be the same length
   ```

What is the code so the columns have the same lengths and I can reshape the data?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: You may look at `tidyr::gather()`, or the functions that superseded it `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.  `stats::reshape` does both but the syntax is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years the reshape operation has evolved and the current popular chose is the `pivot_longer()` function from the "tidyr" package.  This has all of the features from reshape in an easier syntax.

```
#Sample data
newobsHNIR62FL_data_1<-data.frame(CASEID=1:10, v1007_1=1:10, v1007_2=11:20, V1007_3=21:30)

#Pivot longer
tidyr::pivot_longer(newobsHNIR62FL_data_1, 
                    cols=starts_with(c("V", "v")),  
                    names_to = c("name", "id"), 
                    values_to="value", names_sep="_")


# A tibble: 30 x 4
   CASEID name  id    value
    <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
 1      1 v1007 1         1
 2      1 v1007 2        11
 3      1 V1007 3        21
 4      2 v1007 1         2
 5      2 v1007 2        12
 6      2 V1007 3        22
 7      3 v1007 1         3
 8      3 v1007 2        13
 9      3 V1007 3        23
10      4 v1007 1         4
# … with 20 more rows
```